# Problem setting class path without shortcut directory folder in java manifest

Tags: java, manifest.mf

Earlier shortcut was allowed in a server so the code shown below worked fine for executing  a jar file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Sealed: true
Main-Class: org.test.MainClass
Class-Path: /PROGRA~1/Testfolder/hibernate3.jar
 /PROGRA~1/Testfolder/org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
```

Now the system does not allow shortcut directory folder I have to use the full path and system does not identify such path.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Sealed: true
Main-Class: org.test.MainClass
Class-Path: /Program Files (x86)/Testfolder/hibernate3.jar
 /Program Files (x86)/Testfolder/org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
```

How should I specify such absolute path in a manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have blank spaces in your addresses. You should either put them in a path without space or replace them with `%20`. So your `Class-Path` entry would look like this:

```
Class-Path: /C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Testfolder/hibernate3.jar
```

I don't have access to a Windows machine now, if it doesn't work it could be due to the way Windows partition name should be presented in URL. You can also try and address that starts with `file:///C:/` too (or maybe `file:///C/`.

Each entry in the `Class-Path` entry would be considered as a `URL` so you should escape them the way you escape blank space in URL and they should have a protocol.